How should I acknowledge a reviewer who left a negative review?
I submitted a paper to a journal and received three peer reviews. Two reviews were very positive and recommended acceptance, and one was very negative and recommended rejection. This journal does non-anonymous review, so I know the reviewers' identities. The editor accepted my paper despite the one negative review and gave me the opportunity to revise the paper in response to the reviewers' feedback.
I usually thank all reviewers by name in the final version of my papers as a courtesy. In this case, how should I acknowledge the reviewer who recommended rejection (if at all)? On the one hand, she offered valid criticisms that improved the paper, so I think she deserves to be thanked. On the other hand, I wonder if thanking her risks implying that she endorses my paper (which she doesn't, as her review was quite harsh). She may not want her name associated with this paper.

If for whatever reason you feel it's appropriate to name names, how about 'I acknowledge the constructive comments of the reviewers X, Y, and Z and the improvements they brought to this work.'

This may depend on your field, but AFAIK in some fields it is customary to ask people before you acknowledge them in your paper. Do you usually do that before thanking your reviewers by name?

@StephanKolassa No, I’ve never heard of that custom.

Asking them does sound like the common sense approach.

@tparker I think it's field-dependent; see Is it necessary to ask permission before including someone in the acknowledgements of a research paper?

While I acknowledge it might be field-dependent, in my view it would be unethical not to acknowledge someone whose comments improved the paper.

Perhaps this is the time where you break your usual approach and just say "We thank the reviewers for their constructive feedback" or some such. If a situation calls for a different approach, choose a different approach. It doesn't always have to be the same way.


she offered valid criticisms that improved the paper, so I think she deserves to be thanked.

Good instinct. Also, good for you for seeing the value in their review.

I wonder if thanking her risks implying that she endorses my paper

Not in the slightest! Reviewers serve a number of purposes, and you are thanking them for some of them. (I think you probably already feel this way. My guess is that you've never written "we'd like to thank Reviewer 3 for agreeing with us" or "We gratefully acknowledge Reviewer 2's compliments.") To the extent that a reviewer has made the paper better, acknowledge that. If you're worried about implying an endorsement, be specific in your thanks. But beware of damning with faint praise, as in "We acknowledge Reviewer 1's heroic discovery of a missing comma."

I dunno, if I miss an Oxford comma, I'd consider alerting me of that before publication pretty heroic. I have a hill to die on.

"We would like to thank Reviewer 3 for pointing out some subtle errors/glaring errors/unclear bits/entire pages of Lorem Ipsum placeholders. (We also thank reviewers 1 and 2 for their entirely positive reviews, the spineless brown-nosers :-))" Seriously though, the positive reviews might help the editors make their decision, but the negative reviews are the ones that can actually help you improve the paper. If you're thanking anyone, it should be them.

@ScottishTapWater I've seen a missing semicolon disable 200k debit cards for 3 hours on a Friday evening. Pointing out missing punctuation can be quite heroic.

@DavidS - And this is why you use strongly typed, compiled languages :P

@ScottishTapWater ...all of which require the Oxford comma for their comma-delimited array literals.

@ScottishTapWater "I'd like to thank the hero, Reviewer 1, and Reviewer 2."

Since you know the identity, maybe you can reach out per email (or telephone :D) and ask them directly, if they want to be mentioned?

You could ask her if she prefers your usual approach or the suggestion from Wolfgang Bangerth.

Also note: A reviewer being of another opinion does not make your work "bad" or false. It just shows, that there are more takes to it, as you could (maybe) think of. Don't feel rejected. Just acknowledge, that there are others who are interested in the field and also do their way of science and reached out to you.
Someone with a different approach or idea could be a beneficial partner to come into discussion with. I do not know about your topic and the real nature of the review, though.
Is it negative in your opinion, or does it clearly state what points led to the "rejection", and is this argumentation easy to follow and seems reasonable to you?

If so, then that is a good review, ignore the "rejection" result for a moment. It is not ment to stop you from publishing!

If it is not reasonable to you or you have questions or see things differently, contact the reviewer - that is, given you are interested into digging deeper into the field. If not and you just want your paper being published, that is also fine. 2:1 for you is still a green light! (given more reviews it could end up as 43:3. The 2:1 is just an approximation. You have only a low number of reviews being performed in total because of time and costs, etc. It is not supposed to mean, that 50% of all reviews disagree with you! That is/would be a severe misconception!)

Is the review targeted at your work effort and not at the topic, insulting you, etc. then contact and ask for clarification and an apology. If they ignore you, file a complaint somewhere appropriate (idk, at the journal's office maybe?)


Distinguish the case at this point if the reviewer just tells you "he/she did it this way and that way is much better than your way and shows those results which contradict yours", etc. This is not a real rejection. It is a way of trying to communicate that there exists another approach and it is open to debate which one is more suitable. Maybe you can answer back in this case. (It is harder if the topic is like a philosophical one, then the tone might be subjectively more negative but it is still the "open to debate" kind of way). This should not stop you from publishing. It should encourage you to publish and bring everyone forward in this field. Even if it turns out the truth is something different in the end.

Are the points valid, but you think the tone in which they are written is in a manner that does induce negative feelings in you - note that this is subjective. Maybe the reviewer did not ment to hurt your feelings, but just were unable to write it in another way or revise their review because time did not permit. Maybe they are a bit jealous of your work?

Look "behind the facade of the words". Does the tone change? Maybe in the beginning it is harsh, but in the end more objectively okay? Then see it as an improving tendency towards your work and the attempt of helping (aka trying to (maybe overly) "protect" you from doing something wrong). You can still decide to accept the help or not. Both ways are fine - in the sense of: Yes is fine and No is fine. Ignoring it or trying to cover it to forge something, wouldn't be of course.
On a personal note: This is of course not the case here, obviously! You seem very concerned in not to ignore it and doing it right! But also allow you to question if the review is valid/invalid (or parts of it). Because you are allowed to (and even ment to) decide if it isn't - and maybe give feedback to your reasoning, because you are the expert/author of your paper, not the others!
That is what the "No" means. You are also not supposed to take each and every review into account just because it arrived at your inbox! The journal gave you the opportunity to revise, not the obligation.

On the bottom line:
Think of the old days, where scientists like Einstein, Bor etc. all talked to each other, via letters or face-to-face, and discussed their ideas till late into the night. Notably those two had different opinions on the structure of atoms. And even Einstein was not "right" in each and every conception/conviction. Today we follow Bor's approach more. Both are great scientists, though.
